# Writing a <meta> tag using HTMLTextWriter in C# issue

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, meta, htmltextwriter

I'm trying to render a basic HTML webpage using `C#` and `HTMLTextWriter` to output to a `WebBrower` object, but am having issues rendering the `<meta>` tag in my `HTML` output.

**What I am expecting to be output..**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Website</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

**What is currently being output..**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </meta charset="UTF-8"><title>
      My Website
    </title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>
      Hello World!
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Notice how the `<meta>` tag is being output as `<meta charset="UTF-8">` & `</meta charset="UTF-8">` instead of just `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.
>
> **What can I do to correct this issue?**

**Here is the code I am using..**

```
var sw = new StringWriter();
using (var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw)) {
    writer.RenderBeginTag("!DOCTYPE html");
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Html);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Head);
            writer.RenderBeginTag("meta charset=\"UTF-8\"");
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Title);
                writer.Write("SIT323 - My Website");
            writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Body);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.H1);
                writer.Write("Hello World!");
            writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    writer.RenderEndTag();
};
return sw.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it:

```
writer.AddAttribute("charset", "UTF-8");
writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Meta);
// Other needed methods...
writer.RenderEndTag();
```

Result:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

---

The coding pattern for rendering markup elements is as follows:

1. Use the **AddAttribute** method to add any attributes to the element.
2. Use the **RenderBeginTag** method.
3. Use **other methods as needed** to render the content found between the element's opening and closing tags.
4. Use the **RenderEndTag** method.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: @TheAuzzieJesus, please look at the answer code again. Notic you **should** use `RenderEndTag()` after `RenderBeginTag(...)`. In the other words you should finally use a `RenderEndTag()` after each `RenderBeginTag(...)`. Although you can have other methods as needed between them.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to figure it out through trial-and-error luckily.

Comment: @RAM did you actually try your example? to me it gives me <meta charset="utf-8" /> , (self closing), whereas meta does not need />, it should just be a close >

Comment: @joedotnot, meta tag with self closing supports by all browsers but you can use `writer.RenderBeginTag(@"meta charset=""utf-8""");` instead of it.